# PHP - Having trouble inserting dates from a date column with null values. Values are inside an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm making a SQL Server to MySQL program that allows me to sync contents between two identical tables. However, I'm having trouble with inserting date values from a date column that has some of its cells set to NULL. The way this should work is that it should convert each value from the date column into a string using a format function. Since I'm generating each row from an array and running it through a loop, I can't handpick the rows with NULLs out. Here is the code (it's fairly long so i cut some parts out so please bear with me):

```
//SELECT FROM SQL SERVER DB
$mssql_array = array();
$ms_sql = "SELECT * FROM health";
$mssql_query = sqlsrv_query($conn_mssql, $ms_sql);

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($mssql_query))
{
  //turn individual rows into array    
  $mssql_array[] = array(
  'id' => $row['id'], 
  'period' => $row["period"], //date column; has NULLs in it that prevent insert
  'BP' => $row['BP'], 
  'pulserate' => $row['pulserate'],
  'temperature' => $row['temperature'],
  'labresult' => $row['labresult'],
  'waistline' => $row['waistline'],
  'weight' => $row['weight'],
  'BMI' => $row['BMI'],
  'findings' => $row['findings'],
  'diagnosis' => $row['diagnosis'],
  'plano' => $row['plano'] ... );
}

foreach($mssql_array as $key => $value)
{
  //SELECT FROM MySQL DB
  $my_sql = $conn_mysql->prepare(" SELECT * FROM health  
  WHERE id = ? 
  AND period = ?
  AND `BP` = ?
  AND pulserate = ?
  AND temperature = ? 
  AND labresult = ? 
  AND waistline = ? 
  AND weight = ? 
  AND BMI = ? 
  AND findings = ? 
  AND diagnosis = ? 
  AND plano = ? ... ");

  $my_sql->bind_param("issssssssssssssiissssssssiiiiss", $id, $period, $BP, $pulserate, $temperature, $labresult, $waistline, $weight, $BMI, $findings, $diagnosis, $plano ... );

  $id = $value["id"]; 
  $period = $value["period"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //prevents me from converting all date values to string...

  if(is_null($period))
  {
    unset($period);
  }

  $BP = $value["BP"]; 
  $pulserate = $value["pulserate"];
  $temperature = $value["temperature"];
  $labresult = $value["labresult"];
  $waistline = $value["waistline"];
  $weight = $value["weight"];
  $BMI = $value["BMI"];
  $findings = $value["findings"];
  $diagnosis = $value["diagnosis"];
  $plano = $value["plano"]; ...

  $my_sql->execute();
  $num_rows = $my_sql->num_rows();

  $my_sql->close();

  //PREPARE INSERT INTO MySQL DB
  $sql = $conn_mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO `health` VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");//31 total

  $sql->bind_param("issssssssssssssiissssssssiiiiss", $id, $period, $BP, $pulserate, $temperature, $labresult, $waistline, $weight, $BMI, $findings, $diagnosis, $plano ... );

  $id = $value["id"]; 
  $period = $value["period"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //...because it stops the process when it encounters a NULL value

  if(is_null($period))
  {
    unset($period);
  }

  $BP = $value["BP"]; 
  $pulserate = $value["pulserate"];
  $temperature = $value["temperature"];
  $labresult = $value["labresult"];
  $waistline = $value["waistline"];
  $weight = $value["weight"];
  $BMI = $value["BMI"];
  $findings = $value["findings"];
  $diagnosis = $value["diagnosis"];
  $plano = $value["plano"]; ...

    if($num_rows == 0)
      {
        $sql->execute();
      }
}

echo 'Table health from MS SQL DB and table health from MySQL DB are now synced!'."<br>";
echo "<a href='table_updater.php'>Go back to updater</a>";
```

The error it gives me is "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on null" which pretty much tells me that it can't use the format function on the NULL values it encounters. However with the format function it will instead give me the error "Object DateTime could not be converted to string". Is there any way for me to workaround this? I can't change the database values itself because it's not mine.

Comment: you can omit the rows which are null..did you try that?

Comment: how do I do that? if you mean I should use a delete command inside SQL to remove all rows with nulls then i can't do that as some rows do have data in them (just not in date column) and i cant change the database's contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to check and make sure that the variable is an DateTime-object before calling `format()`:

`$period = ($value["period"] instanceof DateTime) ? $value["period"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : null;`

Comment: this is what worked best for me, but do you mind explaining how exactly this line of code works?

Comment: It is kind of If Else condition but it's called ternary opeartor in PHP.

The first part of the answer ( $value["period"] instanceof DateTime ) means, if $value["period"] is instance of DateTime class, then set $value to $value["period"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') and the last part after : means if not then set to null.

Comment: You can read more on ternary opeator here: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator

It's just another sort of IF Else condition but it's usually written in single line so programmers prefer use of ternary operator.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily omit the null rows using mysql select query. Try this query:
    SELECT * FROM health where column_name is NOT NULL;

Comment: thank you, this completely solves everything. i can't believe this solution flew over my head.

Comment: sorry to ask again, but after adding a new row with a NULL date myself i found out that its not inserting it even though it should. Is there a way for it to only ignore the NULLs during datetime to string conversion, yet still add these rows during insertion?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check if a value [is_null()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) and then [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) it from the array.

```php
<?php

$period = $value["period"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if( is_null($period) ){
unset($period);
}

?>
```

Comment: should i put this line of code before i bind parameters, and then call $period again when binding?

Comment: @YMSmash if your problem is when you are inserting the values inside the database, yes.

Comment: code still doesn't work as intended, it still returns the error above. I'll edit my post for you to see if i'm using unset improperly, as I've never used it before

Answer (score 1):

> $period = $value["period"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

There is an awful lot wrong with that one line of code. For starters, either use a factory to translate a value which is presented to PHP as a string or nulll or just carry on treating it as a string/null. Then the rest of the problems just go away:

```
$period = $value["period"];
```

But you need to ensure that you are retrieving the data in a consistent and known format. From MS-SQL you should `CONVERT(period, 20)` to get an ISO 8601 date. MySQL will natively parse this as a string and returns date times in this format.

Unfortunately SQL server is somewhat limited in its handling of dates. While you can use `SET DATEFORMAT` this only works for some data types. So if you wanted to the bulk of the logic in PHP, trying to sniff the format (and the null state) anything you write would be tied to the configured locale in your MSSQL server. I'll not bother offering an example because if you cut and paste my code and it doesn't work, you'll think there's something wrong with the code rather than it merely expecting a different locale than what you have configured.

I don't know off the top of my head if a NULL value is returned as a null PHP variable or an empty string by the MSSQL extension. But both are zero length strings, hence a generic solution would be....

```
$bindable=strlen($avalue) ? null : $avalue;
```

Comment: sorry, but since i'm still new to PHP i'm not quite sure what you meant with some of the things you said, namely: 1) "For starters, either use a factory to translate a value which is presented to PHP as a string or null", I don't know what a factory would mean in this context 2) "From MS-SQL you should CONVERT(period, 20) to get an ISO 8601 date.", also not familiar with what the CONVERT function does in MSSQL, or what an ISO 8601 is, and 3) `$bindable=strlen($avalue) ? null : $avalue;` how does this line of code work, and where does it fit in my code?

Comment: None of the things you have queried here are specific to PHP. Presumably you are also new to programming. Perhaps you are overstretching a bit here.